# Mongoose populate returns empty array with a simple,non-nested population

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to populate a model but I am getting a empty array in return. I went throught every stack overflow answer but nothing solved my issue.
Here's my main schema:

```
const companySchema = new Schema({
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    img:{data: Buffer,contentType: String},
    users:[{
        name:String,
        email:String,
        allottedWarehouse:String,
    }],
    brands:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Brand'}],
    warehouses:{type:Array},
    shops:{type:Array}
})
```

Here's how I am trying to populate

```
exports.getCompanyDetails = function(req,res){
   Company.findById(req.params.id)
   .populate('brands')
        .exec(function(err,selectedCompany){
            if(err){
             res.json('Something went wrong!')
            }
            console.log(selectedCompany.brands)
            res.json(selectedCompany);
        })
    }
```

But in database it's just empty brands array,no id reference at all.
When I return it in res.json,it's empty too.

Here's my simple brand schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const BrandSchema = new Schema(
  {
   name: {type: String, required: true},
   packSize:{type: Number, required: true},

  })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Brand',BrandSchema);
```

I so badly need your help on this. Please look at it guys!Tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: If 'in database it's just empty brands array' then it's normal that the populate also returns an empty array, maybe the problem is an insertion problem not populate problem?

Comment: I meant in brands model,I have brands,no problem to post and retrieve that. But in company model where I am trying to refernece brands model,that is empty.